# Play 2.x: Binding model which contains a list to the template

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have two models User and Address.

```
public class User extends Model{
   public String name;
   public List<Address> addresses;
}

public class Address extends Model{
   public String street;
   public String house;
}
```

I have a template to add a user.

```
@(form: Form[User])

@helper.form(action=routes.User.add())
{
   <label>Add User<label>
   @text(form("name"), label="Name")
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
}
```

In my controller I have the add method.

```
public static Results add()
{
   Form<User> filledForm = userForm.bindFromRequest();
   User user = filledForm.get();
}
```

I have skipped unnecessary information like the error handling.
Now how can I bind the addresses? I want to be able to add multiple addresses in the form.

In Play 1.1 I have seen things like POJO collections but I am using 2.3.

Comment: Do you want to edit both, User and Address(es) in one form ? Looks like good place to use AJAX

Comment: Yup... When I create a user I want to be able to add addresses too and save it. Ideally, there should be at least one Address added before the user can save the form

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment probably JavaScript and AJAX would be most comfortable solution, you can i.e. create an User as unactive and activate him only when at least one address is added later.

Other solution can be using custom class with fields from both (User and Address) so after validating all required fields you can create an User and associated Address.

### Sample

**User** model:

```
public class User extends Model {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    public List<Address> addresses; // This field doesn't keep relations it informs that relation is kept in `user` field of `Address` model

}
```

**Address** model:

```
public class Address extends Model {
    
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;
    
    public String street;
    public String house;

}
```

**UserAdmin** controller:

```
public static class UserWithAddress { //This is our class for validating data for user and his `primary` address

    // User's fields
    @Required
    public String firstName;

    @Required
    public String lastName;

    // Address' fields
    @Required
    public String street;

    @Required
    public String house;

}

public static Result addUserWithAddress() {
    Form<UserWithAddress> userForm = Form.form(UserWithAddress.class);
    return ok(userWithAddressView.render(userForm));
}

public static Result saveUserWithAddress() {
    Form<UserWithAddress> userForm = Form.form(UserWithAddress.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (userForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(userWithAddressView.render(userForm));
    }

    // form is valid, let's extract data from form, create and save both objects
    UserWithAddress data = userForm.get();

    User user = new User();
    user.firstName = data.firstName;
    user.lastName = data.lastName;
    user.save(); // Save new user before creating new Address, cause we need a new ID to associate...

    Address address = new Address();
    address.user = user;
    address.street = data.street;
    address.house = data.house;
    address.save();

    return ok("Hooray you're registered now! And we know where you live ;)");
}
```

**userWithAddressView.scala.html** view

```
@(userForm: Form[controllers.UsersAdmin.UserWithAddress])

@main(title = "Input your basic data and address data") {

    @helper.form(action=routes.UsersAdmin.saveUserWithAddress()){

        @helper.inputText(userForm("firstName"))
        @helper.inputText(userForm("lastName"))
        @helper.inputText(userForm("street"))
        @helper.inputText(userForm("house"))
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>

    }

}
```

Comment: In terms of the custom classes, how would it work if the user can keep adding addresses? Looking forward to some code

Comment: This sample shows you how to create user with basic address data at once, for adding more addresses you need to create methods like `newAddressForUser(Long userId)`

Comment: I just found this - @helper.repeat - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers wouldn't that work better?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have gone ahead with using the repeat helper. It was a lot cleaner for what I wanted. +1

Answer (score 1):

So I built it using the @helper.repeat. The best example is in the samples provided by Play. It's called forms.

For a quick reference, the description can be found here - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFormHelpers

```
@helper.inputText(userForm("name"))

@helper.repeat(userForm("emails"), min = 1) { emailField =>

    @helper.inputText(emailField)

}
```

For the address example:

```
@(form: Form[User])

@helper.form(action=routes.User.add())
{
   <label>Add User<label>
   @text(form("name"), label="Name")

   @helper.repeat(form("addresses"), min= 1){ address =>
      @helper.inputText(address("street"))
      @helper.inputText(address("house"))      
   }
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
}
```

Validation works as normal if you add the required annotaion over `street` and `house`. The only thing you need to do is add the `@Valid` (`javax.validation.Valid`) annotation over the list of addresses.

```
@Valid
public List<Address> addresses;
```

For adding and removing addresses, the sample is the best to look through.

Comment: O, nice, can you also show as how to use Address object in `repeated` helper, that will be helpful for other guys, (also with validation and binding)